# Is it possible to define a semi-annual frequency for a python scikits.timeseries time_series object?

Tags: python, scipy, scikits

According to the scikits.timeseries module the following frequencies are available when defining a time_series object:

- Annual Frequencies, Quarterly frequencies, Monthly, Weekly, Daily etc. A full list is shown on the documentation link: http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/core.constants.html#scikits.timeseries.const.freq_constants

The frequencies **exclude** semi-annual (twice a year).

How would one define a semi-annual frequency for a scikits.timeseries.time_series object? Does a work-around exist?

Comment: Define Quarterly frequency and fill it to 50%?

Comment: Hi eumiro, could you provide a small example perhaps? Do you mean something like this: Q1 -- Q2 1.0 Q3 -- Q4 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define quaterly frequency and fill it to 50%:

```
import scikits.timeseries as ts

dates = ts.date_array(start_date=ts.Date('Q', '2009-01'),
                      end_date=ts.Date('Q', '2011-01'))
data = ts.TimeSeries(np.arange(9), dates=dates, mask=1-dates.quarter%2)

# returns:
timeseries([0 -- 2 -- 4 -- 6 -- 8],
   dates = [2009Q1 ... 2011Q1],
   freq  = Q-DEC)
```

Comment: Thank you eumiro, I've tried it out and it seems to do the trick! One potential gotcha: data.data.tolist() will return list with masked values e.g. [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], while data.tolist() correctly fills masked values with None.